# How would you perform ceiling division?

Tags: rust, integer-division

Avoiding a conversion over to floating point is necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Rust 1.73 Update:**

There is [`u32::div_ceil()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.div_ceil) on stable now.

While [`i32::div_ceil()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.div_ceil) is unstable on nightly.

---

Rust stable v1.61.0 branch: `ceil(a/b)` is `(a + b - 1) / b` if you know that that addition won't overflow.

Comment: I want to point out that this only works when both arguments are nonnegative. A full implementation of `ceil` will look more like this: `if a > 0 && b > 0 { (a - 1) / b + 1 } else if a < 0 && b < 0 { (a + 1) / b + 1 } else { a / b }`. This is because integer division in Rust is not floor division, it always rounds to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`divrem`](https://docs.rs/divrem/1.0.0/divrem/index.html) crate, concretely [`div_ceil`](https://docs.rs/divrem/1.0.0/divrem/trait.DivCeil.html):

Answer (score 1):

From the Rust standard library (minimum version 1.73)

u32: [div_ceil](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.div_ceil)

u64: [div_ceil](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html#method.div_ceil)

```
// pub const fn div_ceil(self, rhs: Self) -> Self;
//     Calculates the quotient of self and rhs, 
//     rounding the result towards positive infinity.

let integer: u32 = 122023;
let result = integer.div_ceil(10000); // 13

assert_eq!(7_u32.div_ceil(4), 2);
```